# What do I call my paid account?

Tags: synonyms

I have created a web application that has two offerings, one is free, the other is paid. The paid version has exactly the same functionality as the free version, it's just that it can be used with more people.

I am struggling with what to call the paid account.

Here are some I have rejected.

- "pro" or "professional" - Implies that if you use the free version,
  your not professional.
- "premium" - Sounds expensive.
- "gold, silver, bronze" - doesn't really work with two offerings, and
  implies class.
- "restricted/full" - Implies less/more functionality.

Comment: How is it exactly the same functionality if it can be used with more people?

Comment: Any of these work, and is just a matter of taste. There is no correct answer for this question. Common usage is that the literal meanings of these (being only for professionals, or being expensive, etc.) is generally not what they mean. You may be looking for a "personal/site license" distinction.

Answer (score 2):

> it's just that it can be used with more people

How about `Team` or a derivative there-of such as `TeamFlow` or `TeamWork`